# How to add HTML select/option elemnt into jQuery.msgBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, msgbox

[jQuery.msgBox](http://dotctor.github.io/jQuery.msgBox/) is a plug-in to make it smarter to display messages. I use jQuery.msgBox in my code. It works fine, but I need to add an HTML select/option element to the displayed message. How can this be done?

Please look at an example code I use:

```js
$.msgBox({
            title: "Nowy jadłospis",
            type: "prompt",
            inputs: [{ header: "Podaj nową nazwę jadłospisu."},
                     { header: "Podaj opis jadłospisu."},
                     { header: "Podaj komentarz do jadłospisu."}],
            buttons: [{ value: "OK" }, {value:"Anuluj"}],
            success: function (result, values) {
                if (result == "OK") {

                    do something...

                }else{
                    $.msgBox({
                        title:"Błąd!",
                        content:"Podano nieprawidłową nazwę jadłospisu.",
                        type:"error"
                        });
                }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: ` HTML select/option element` What do you mean by this? Do you want to add HTML element into the message?

Comment: From the documentation, the library you're using only allows the use of `text` and `password` inputs in a prompt-style dialog box. You cannot add your own custom HTML. I would suggest you find a more up to date library which suits your needs - that one is 10 years old

Comment: At http://dotctor.github.io/jQuery.msgBox/

Author has added this message, **better go with bootstrap**.

Currently, this code is **not maintained**.
Alternatives such as bootstrap are recommended.
See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals for modals in bootstrap.

Comment: I have found this https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-message-box/#quick-demo. There is an INPUT select1 type select. This is what I was looking for, but not necessarily with this library.

Comment: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-message-box@3.2.2/dist/messagebox.min.css`
You can just include these resources

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4gJBAu3NKUQp1HMUbrK9?p=preview&preview @bzc0fq check this link